# OS X virtualenv Pillow and Jpeg support

Tags: python, django, osx-mavericks, virtualenv

I have Pillow working on my OS X Mavericks machine. But when I try to install it in a virtualenv, I can't seem to get JPEG support working.

Here's the summary output of `pip install Pillow` in the virtualenv:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version      Pillow 2.5.3
platform     darwin 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
             [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
*** JPEG support not available
*** OPENJPEG (JPEG2000) support not available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** LIBTIFF support not available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS2 support not available
*** WEBP support not available
*** WEBPMUX support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It seems I could try to edit setup.py to point to the relevant libs, but I'm new to virtualenv, and don't know where setup.py is.

EDIT:
Well, I solved it by linking from the virtualenv to the working Pillow library.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `libjpeg` first, as the doc says:

> http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries
>
> libjpeg provides JPEG functionality.

Install `libjpeg` using homebrew: `brew install libjpeg`

Comment: Thanks, I've already done that and it works. I guess I wasn't clear in my initial question. Pillow is working with jpeg support on my main environment, but not in my virtualenv.

Comment: Download the pillow package, then uncompress it, run `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

So, my solution was to link to the working install of Pillow from the virtualenv.